# Run ruby script in background without using screen

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ssh

I have a two scripts in the Rails environment which have to run 24/7. I'm working on a remote server, so I need to start the scripts using `ssh`, which means I need to keep the ssh windows open all the time.

I'm searching for a simple way to run these scripts in the background so they aren't canceled as soon as I close the ssh connection.

I don't want to use `screen`. I think there must be simpler way to handle this. Isn't there?

Comment: Have you looked at god and/or monit?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I think the most basic solution would be `nohup`:

```
nohup myscript &> /dev/null &
```

Comment: yes this is perfect and we can redirect output to log file via :
nohup ruby myscript.rb > myscript.log & 

I have just tried it with ruby script, and also you can check if its running via command: ps -fu username

Answer (score 4):

You can disown a script:

```
 ruby script.rb &!
```

STDOUT/STDERR are still attached to the current shell, but the `ruby` process isn't a child of the shell anymore, so it won't get killed if you close the terminal.

Answer (score 2):

Check [Daemons](https://github.com/ghazel/daemons). It's a toolkit for converting a script to a controllable daemon.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

- [runit](http://smarden.org/runit/)
- [supervisord](http://supervisord.org/)

For daemonizing

Or some ruby stuff: https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/#Background_Processing for background processing